# MySQL Errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know why i am getting the following error message?

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

```
CREATE TABLE meter (
    `code` CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    location_code CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pri_meter 
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
CONSTRAINT for_meter
    FOREIGN KEY (location_code) REFERENCES location (`code`));

CREATE TABLE location(
    `code` CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    company VARCHAR(30),
    `type` VARCHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT pri_location 
    PRIMARY KEY (`code`));

CREATE TABLE reading(
    meter_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `when` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    display DECIMAL(9,3) NOT NULL,
    estimate BIT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pri_reading 
    PRIMARY KEY (`when`, meter_code),
CONSTRAINT for_reading
    FOREIGN KEY (meter_code) REFERENCES meter (`code`));

CREATE INDEX index_meter ON meter (location_code);
CREATE INDEX index_reading ON reading (meter_code);
```

Comment: Create `location` table first. You can't reference a table column when the table being referenced is not there yet (here you have a reference to table location upon creation of meter table).

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `location` table first.

You can't reference a table column when the table being referenced is not there yet.

In your example you have a reference to table `location` upon creation of `meter` table.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating a `Foreign Key` table you have to:

```
1. Create the Primary Key table first.
2. Must better to create all tables first without any Primary Key or Foreign Key Constraints.(Optional)
3. After that, create the Primary key and the Foreign Key Constraints of it.
```

This is just an idea

Answer (score 0):

1. before recreating all tables

```
    -- Pseudocode
    foreach table
         if the table references another table
             then drop the referencing table;
```

2. recreate tables in order:

   1. create all referenced tables
   2. create all referencing tables

```sql
    -- before recreating all tables:

    -- delete the referencing tables 
    -- causing the error
    DROP TABLE table_4_references_table_3;
    DROP TABLE table_3_references_table_1;

    -- recreate tables in order:

    -- A. create tables that have no foreign
    --    keys 
    CREATE TABLE table_1 (
        ...
    );
    CREATE TABLE table_2 (
        ...
    );

    -- B. create table 3 that has foreign
    --    key references to table 1 above
    CREATE TABLE table_3_references_table_1 (
        ...
    );

    -- C. create table 4 that has foreign
    --    key references to table 3 above
    CREATE TABLE table_4_references_table_3(
        ...
    );
```

2. Also in case you need it later: Note order of indexes in CONSTRAINT clauses is order in CREATE TABLE clause:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE my_table_1 (

        -- order in CREATE TABLE clause
        appears_first VARCHAR(200),
        appears_second VARCHAR(200),

        -- same order of indexes in CONSTRAINT clauses
        CONSTRAINT  
            UNIQUE INDEX (
                appears_first,
                appears_second
            ),

        CONSTRAINT 
            FOREIGN KEY (appears_second)
            REFERENCES my_table_2(appears_second)
            ON DELETE RESTRICT
            ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
```

Comment: please add additional information to help SO in getting doubts clear from your answer. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information